# Event based calendar in drupal

Tags: events, drupal, calendar, drupal-7, fullcalendar

I need to show the calendar events based upon the events in drupal.

But i have searched in all places in the internet. but i have not got the solutions.
In drupal the calendar is showing according to month, year and day based, **but not based upon the event**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Events [calendar feature module](http://drupal.org/project/events_calendar_feature), here's a [step by step tutorial](http://drupal.org/node/1250714) for how to use it.

Hope this works... Muhammad.

Comment: Thank you for the Effort Muhammad. But i am not asking this. I need to display the calendar in Event based. For Example. Consider you are having three events in month July,Aug, Sep respectively. I need to display the calendar based upon the events.the vents will be displayed  as per the month in the calendar

Comment: I will say for example attached the below table if you get confused<table><tr><td>1</td></tr></table>

Comment: Could you give me a screenshot for what you're trying to do?! It'd be much easier :)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to show events listed in a traditional month based format - ever - why don't you just create an Event content type, then create a simple View that lists the events sorted by date, but in an HTML list format?

Or, better yet, use the regular Calendar module, then add a display to the set of views it creates that is a simple list. There may even be a display that does this already (I think it's called 'mini-display' or something similar). That way, if you ever do need a month based view of your events, you still have it in your back pocket.